# How to read/write data from/to external hardware in omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I want to do a hardware-in-loop experiment using oment++,is there any way could exetend the omnet++ to read/write data from an external equipment.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of modules in OMNeT++ is written in C++ therefore one can use any additional library for C++ to communicate with external hardware.